# internal implementation details of XML parsing using java xml parser

Tags: parsing

can anyone tell how an XML (Java) parser will parse the XML document( i mean to say the internal implementation details of XML parsing)?

Answer (score 1):

The exact algorithm probably varies quite a bit between different implementations.

[Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/) is a widely used XML parser for Java. It is open source so you can [download the Java source code](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/source-repository.html) to see how it is implemented.

[Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) is a parser generator for Java that makes writing a parser for languages like XML somewhat easier than doing it by hand. The Antlr documentation has some information about how you would write an XML parser using Antlr: [Parsing XML](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Parsing+XML). This covers most of the concepts of how such parsers work if you're more interested in a high level view.